# Extract string from html file

Tags: html, ios, html-parsing

Given this portion of a html file, I am looking for a way to extract the text starting from "Metronidazole ...." to the end under "INDICATIONS & USAGE".

Any suggestions?

```
<div class="Section" data-sectionCode="34067-9">
<a name="section-4"></a>
<p></p>
<h1>
<span class="Bold">INDICATIONS &amp; USAGE
</span>
</h1>
<p class="First">Metronidazole vaginal gel USP, 0.75% is indicated in the treatment of bacterial vaginosis (formerly referred to as <span class="Italics">Haemophilus</span> vaginitis, <span class="Italics">Gardnerella</span> vaginitis, nonspecific vaginitis, <span class="Italics">Corynebacterium</span> vaginitis, or anaerobic vaginosis).</p>
<dl>
<dt></dt>
<dd>
<p class="First">
<span class="Bold">NOTE:</span> For purposes of this indication, a clinical diagnosis of bacterial vaginosis is usually defined by the presence of a homogeneous vaginal discharge that (a) has a pH of greater than 4.5, (b) emits a &ldquo;fishy&rdquo; amine odor when mixed with a 10% KOH solution, and (c) contains clue cells on microscopic examination. Gram&rsquo;s stain results consistent with a diagnosis of bacterial vaginosis include (a) markedly reduced or absent <span class="Italics">Lactobacillus</span> morphology, (b) predominance of <span class="Italics">Gardnerella</span> morphotype, and (c) absent or few white blood cells.</p>
</dd>
</dl>
<p>Other pathogens commonly associated with vulvovaginitis, e.g., <span class="Italics">Trichomonas vaginalis</span>, <span class="Italics">Chlamydia trachomatis</span>, <span class="Italics">N</span>. <span class="Italics">gonorrhoeae</span>, <span class="Italics">Candida albicans</span>, and <span class="Italics">Herpes simplex</span> virus should be ruled out.</p>
</div>
```

## INDICATIONS & USAGE

Metronidazole vaginal gel USP, 0.75% is indicated in the treatment of bacterial vaginosis (formerly referred to as Haemophilus vaginitis, Gardnerella vaginitis, nonspecific vaginitis, Corynebacterium vaginitis, or anaerobic vaginosis).

NOTE: For purposes of this indication, a clinical diagnosis of bacterial vaginosis is usually defined by the presence of a homogeneous vaginal discharge that (a) has a pH of greater than 4.5, (b) emits a “fishy” amine odor when mixed with a 10% KOH solution, and (c) contains clue cells on microscopic examination. Gram’s stain results consistent with a diagnosis of bacterial vaginosis include (a) markedly reduced or absent Lactobacillus morphology, (b) predominance of Gardnerella morphotype, and (c) absent or few white blood cells.

Other pathogens commonly associated with vulvovaginitis, e.g., Trichomonas vaginalis, Chlamydia trachomatis, N. gonorrhoeae, Candida albicans, and Herpes simplex virus should be ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some old school tricks like,

1. First convert the NSString to Character Array (Source Array).
2. Create an empty target Character Array.
3. Start adding the character from source to target Array using logic.
4. If you find '<' (start of html tag) character stop adding character in target Array till you find '>' (end of html tag) character.

Or you could use another Trick like

```
NSString* startTag = @"<";
NSString* endTag = @">";
NSString* replacementString = @"";

 while ([str rangeOfString:startTag].length != 0 && [str rangeOfString:endTag].length != 0)
{

  NSRange range1 = [str rangeOfString:startTag];
  NSRange range2 = [str rangeOfString:endTag];

  if(range1.location>range2.location)
   break;

NSRange newRange;
newRange.length =range2.location-range1.location+range2.length;
newRange.location = range1.location;
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:newRange withString:replacementString];

  }
```

then you can find the text as you said under "INDICATIONS & USAGE" by rangeOfString Method , your desire text should be after this range.